# When and how can I use the Clone() method in real world situation?

Tags: java, class, clone

I think the title is straight forward. I understood how clone() works and override in my class. However, I couldn't imagine a simple real world example where the clone() method is necessary. Can you give me a simple example where, when, and how can I use clone in my classes?

Answer (score 0):

In Java classes are call-by-value. That means that when you pass an object to a method, this method has access to that object, not a copy of that object. So if the method manipulates that object, the original object also changes. If you want to prevent that, then you can pass object.clone() to the method.